# Dragging and Dropping of view in Android 2.2

Tags: android, layout

How to do drag/drop functionality to move a view from one position to another position in the current layout using a graphical drag and drop gesture in API level 8 as this functionality comes in Android 2.3

Thanks Saurabh!

Comment: Did you find the solution, as I have a same situation to trace out? Can you please help me how you implement this?

Comment: I have done that by using touchListener. I handle click, longpressed and touch all in touch listener by calculating time difference to touch on screen and move a view position according to my touch position. It may help u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi here i give the link and go this post and find the solution of your question.
where i post my whole activity code for everyone.
so i think it`s help you best of luck

[How to implement Drag and Drop in android 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306243/how-to-implement-drag-and-drop-in-android-2-2/11431727#11431727)

and also find the another solution of how to do this.then use this link

http://code.google.com/p/rxwen-blog-stuff/source/browse/#svn/trunk/android/drag

And Another is

http://code.google.com/p/android-drag-and-drop-basic/source/browse/src/edu/sbcc/cs123/draganddropbasic/DragAndDropBasicActivity.java

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you would need to listen for the touch of the user on the screen, identify the object that is being selected using the x/y coordinates, and then when the user releases the click, identify where they released. If it has changed, then work out where the new location is, and pass the object originally clicked to the other view, and remove it from the old one, placing it in the position clicked on the new view.

Look up OnClickListener for more information on how this works, in the Android Developer guides